# How to specify the return type of a method that returns a list of values in StarUML?

Tags: uml, class-diagram, staruml

I have two classes (say **Database** and **Record**). In Database class, I have a method named getRecords() that returns a list of Record objects.

In Java, the above method can be written as:

```
List<Record> getRecords(){..}
```

In StarUML, while designing Class diagram, I tried giving

```
+getRecords() : Record[0..*]
```

But StarUML refused to create method like above. When I tried with the one below, it works

```
+getRecords() : ArrayList<Record>
```

But this is more specific to Java. I want to implement something like Record[0..*] in StarUML. Is it possible to write methods in such format or the Java style of return type is the only solution ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I don't know why StarUML refuses to parse the text, but you can still create it via model.

1. Add the operation and call it `getRecords()`
2. Right-click on the operation (in diagram or model), and select Add > Parameter
3. Select parameter in *Model Explorer* (probably the parameter is already selected when you created it) and set the `direction` parameter to `return`. This is how UML represents return types.
4. (Configure the type, multiplicity, and anything else you need.)

Note that the default collection in UML is `Set`, so you should check `isOrdered`, as `List` is an ordered collection.